# Closure gets the wrong value, how to figure out how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I've created a test case for a closure problem that I've with socket IO. Here's the code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

function Session (id) {
    console.log('before connection:', id);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('in connection:', id);
        socket.on('foo', function (){}) // just to keep it running as there is a listener
    });
}

setTimeout(function () {
  var client_id1 = get_client_id_from_database(); // returns 55
  var session1 = new Session(client_id);
});
setTimeout(function () {
  var client_id2 = get_another_id_from_database(); // returns 99
  var session2 = new Session(client_id2);
});
```

The problem is with lines:

```
console.log('before connection:', id);
```

and

```
console.log('in connection:', id);
```

Now when I create two connections to my app, I get this output:

```
before connection: 55
before connection: 99
in connection: 99
in connection: 99
```

However I'm expecting two messages for `55` and two messages for `99`:

```
before connection: 55
before connection: 99
in connection: 99
in connection: 55
```

Something like this.

Does anyone know how to solve this closure problem? Apparently `id` in the Session gets closed and I get somehow get `99` always for the `id`.

Comment: Have you gone through Resig's excellent tutorial http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ ?  You'll learn how to handle this and more.

Comment: You're doing `var session1 = new Session(client_id);` when you probably mean `var session1 = new Session(client_id1);`

Comment: Evidently only one listener the last for `'connection'` on `io` is ever going to fire. The problem has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: @DanD. I create two connections to my app, sorry about forgetting to say that. I'm update question.

Comment: Both connections cause only the last set listener to fire. Which in this case happens to be the one with the id of 99. Why are you attempting to listen for 'connection' twice?

Comment: @DanD. I somehow need to `id` to be accessible inside of new connection handler. So I put the connection handler inside of constructor of Session. Every session (connection) should get a new ID, but somehow id's get reused like in my case, I get 99 repeated.

Comment: I don't know what you are attempting to do. But it is highly likely that is not the way to do it.

Comment: This is just a test case... What I try to do is put the Session in session.js file. And then from main.js file create `new Session(id)`. However I need this `id` in every connection, so like in my test case, I put socket.io inside Session function.

Comment: I think it should work properly, I didn't find any problem in code except below lines.

setTimeout(function () {
  var client_id1 = get_client_id_from_database(); // returns 55
  var session1 = new Session(client_id1);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself. The problem was that in each Session constructor I was adding an event listener for 'connection'. The first connection would work, but the second one would trigger two events. The third connection three events, and so on.

The solution is to save sockets in a global variable outside Session:

```
var connections = {};
function Session (id) {
    console.log('before connection:', id);
    connections[id] = socket;
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    connections[id] = socket;
}
```